# Condition Decorator with Runtime Data

Tags: c#, simple-injector

Using Simple Injector I can see that I can register decorators based on information available at design-time, but is it possible to get the same behavior with run-time data?

Here is a simple example (in reality there are many more decorators):

```
public class LineageIdDecorator : IDataReader
{
    public LineageIdDecorator(IDataReader dataReader)
    {
        _dataReader = dataReader;
    }
    // Implementation skipped...
}

public class RuntimeConfig
{
    public bool IncludeLineage { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public string Query { get; set; }
}

public class DataSource
{
    public IDataReader CreateDataReader(RuntimeConfig config)
    {
        var connection = new SqlConnection(config.ConnectionString);
        var command = new SqlCommand(config.Query, connection);
        connection.Open();
        IDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteQuery();
        if (config.IncludeLineage)
        {
            dataReader = new LineageIdDecorator(dataReader);
        }
        return dataReader;
    }
}
```

With the important part being:

```
if (config.IncludeLineage)
{
    dataReader = new LineageIdDecorator(dataReader);
}
```

Am I stuck always instantiating these decorators myself? Or am I missing some Simple Injector feature?

## Edit

Based on Steven's answer I am now trying to use scope and an IRuntimeConfigurationProvider to construct the decorators with the information they need to either be enabled or disabled. I am providing more context.

My goal is to write a plugin for an in-house workflow system. The contract looks like this:

```
public interface IWorkflowAction<T>
{
    async Task<Markdown> Execute(T marshalledData)
}
```

This contract is company wide and I cannot change it. Markdown is a class provided in the same internal nuget package as the contract. T represents the type of configuration data I expect in my action. The host takes JSON, configured in a web site by a user, and automatically materializes it to the type I specify.

```
public class MyWorkflowAction : IWorkflowAction<List<RuntimeConfiguration>>
{
    private readonly MyActionEngine _engine;
    public MyWorkflowAction()
    {
        container = new Container();
        // register components
        container.Verify();
        _engine = container.GetInstance<MyActionEngine>
    }

    public async Task<Markdown> Execute(List<RuntimeConfiguration> runtimeConfiguration)
    {
        foreach (var config in runtimeConfiguration)
        {
            await _engine.SendAsync(config);
        }
        _engine.Complete();
        await _engine.Completion;
        return new Markdown();
    }
}
```

This is my entry point. I create `MyWorkflowEngine` in the constructor using SimpleInjector. `MyWorkflowEngine` is an implementation of an `IActionBlock<T>` from the TPL DataFlow library.

Each request is queued using `SendAsync` and executes in parallel depending on how app.config values have configured the MaxDOP.

The code inside `MyActionEngine` is manually building a an `IDataReader` and applying the required decorators based on the values in the config object.
Once all the work has been queued the action block is told to expect no more data. We then wait for completion and exit.

It's clear to me that I need to use the `AsyncScopedLifestyle`, but I'm still unclear on how to construct the decorators at run-time if they depend on the IRuntimeProviderContext, which itself depends on the current instance of the configuration object.

Comment: There is pretty good documentation available! Decorators can be found here: https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aop.html

Comment: The construction of a new `Container` instance within the `MyWorkflowAction` constructor is worrying to me. You would typically have one `Container` instance per application, and such container would build a large object graph. Every new `MyWorkflowAction` creates a new `Container` instance which can have severe performance implications. Why aren't you injecting `MyActionEngine` into `MyWorkflowAction`'s ctor and use a global `Container` to construct `MyWorkflowAction` instances?

Comment: I just noticed the following line of code: `IDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteQuery()`. I didn't take much attention to it before, but since Simple Injector isn't creating the data reader implementation (the `command` is), it wouldn't make much sense to let your DI Container configure a decorator that can wrap that returned `IDataReader`. The value returned from `command.ExecuteQuery()` is **runtime data**. In other words: do not try to configure and resolve your `LineageIdDecorator` through Simple Injector. So I think your `CreateDataReader` method is fine as it is.

Comment: The only thing that worries me is the lack of disposal of the `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects, but you might have removed that part for brevity.

Comment: @Steven I don't control the real entry point for the running process. That is hosted for me elsewhere and out of my control. The ctor or static ctor of `MyWorkflowAction` is the earliest I'm handed control. The host doesn't know anything about my objects, only that I implement a simple contract it understands. I think I'm happy to create these decorators myself now. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious related to DI patterns or Simple Injector.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not so much that you *can’t* apply decorators conditionally based on runtime information in Simple Injector, but this is a practice that is discouraged.

Making registrations based on runtime information is discouraged, because it makes your configuration hard to impossible to verify, since verification depends on being able to construct object graphs, which is often impossible, since this required runtime information is often not available at the time of verification (which could be at application startup or when running the test suite).

Instead you should not change the structure of your object graph based on runtime information, but instead use this runtime information to decide which call graph to take on an already constructed object graph.

Because of this discouragement, the built-in decorator facilities do not allow registering decorators conditionally based on runtime information. There are [examples](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/blob/master/src/SimpleInjector.CodeSamples/RuntimeDecoratorExtensions.cs) of how to do runtime based decoration in the code samples project in the Github repository, but they are mere examples, again, I would recommend against using them.

Instead of applying the decorator at runtime conditionally, apply the decorator constantly, and implement the branching *inside* the decorator, based on the runtime data that the decorator retrieves at the time it is invoked.

This might look as follows:

```
public class LineageIdDecorator : IDataReader
{
    public LineageIdDecorator(
        IDataReader decoratee, IRuntimeConfigProvider configProvider) { .. }

    // IDataReader methods
    public object DoSomething()
    {
        if (configProvider.Config.IncludeLineage)
        {
            // run decorated behavior
        }

        return decoratee.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Here a new abstraction `IRuntimeConfigProvider` is introduced that allows retrieving the runtime configuration *at runtime*, oppose to injecting it into the constructor.
Another approach would be to split the runtime selection behavior and the actual behavior of the decorator. This can be important when the decorator contains a lot of logic. Splitting them would into two decorators would make each decorator have a single responsibility. This would reduce the `LineageIdDecorator` back to your original implementation, and the second implementation could look much like this:

```
public class RuntimeDecoratorSelector : IDataReader
{
    private readonly IDataReader decoratedDecoratee;
    private readonly IDataReader originalDecoratee;
    private readonly IRuntimeConfigProvider configProvider;

    public RuntimeDecoratorSelector(
        IDataReader decoratedDecoratee, IDataReader originalDecoratee,
        IRuntimeConfigProvider configProvider)
    {
        this.decoratedDecoratee = decoratedDecoratee;
        this.originalDecoratee = originalDecoratee;
        this.configProvider = configProvider;
    }

    private IDataReader Decoratee => 
        configProvider.Config.IncludeLineage ? decoratedDecoratee : originalDecoratee;

    // IDataReader methods
    public object DoSomething()
    {
        return Decoratee.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Both the decorated service as the original service are injected into this selector class, together with the `IRuntimeConfigProvider`.

Registering this new RuntimeDecoratorSelector, together with the original LineageIdDecorator and implementation becomes now a bit more complex, since it involves making conditional registrations, compared to decorators. Here’s how to make these registrations:

```
container.RegisterConditional<IDataReader, DataReaderImpl>(
    c => c.Consumer?.ImplementationType == typeof(LineageIdDecorator) 
        || c.Consumer?.Target.Name.StartsWith("original") == true);

container.RegisterConditional<IDataReader, LineageIdDecorator>(
    c => c.Consumer?.Target.Name.StartsWith("decorated") == true);

container.RegisterConditional<IDataReader, RuntimeDecoratorSelector>(c => !c.Handled);
```

What we’re doing here is registering the `DataReaderImpl` conditionally and telling it to be injected into the `LineageIdDecorator` or into any constructor argument (of type `IDataReader`) where the argument name starts with *original*. This will be one of the parameters of the `RuntimeDecoratorSelector`.

The `LineageIdDecorator` is registered conditionally, but it is instructed to be injected into any constructor argument (of type `IDataReader`) where the argument name starts with *decorated*. This will obviously be the second argument of the `RuntimeDecoratorSelector`.

Last but not least, we’re registering the `RuntimeDecoratorSelector`. Perhaps surprisingly, it has to be registered conditionally as well. That’s because Simple Injector is very strict, and will detect when multiple registrations overlap. It forces you to very explicit of what it is you want. Not making this registration conditional, would cause it to be applicable to its own constructor arguments, which would cause a cyclic dependency. By stating that it should be injected into any consumer, when there isn’t already a registration that was handled, we make this registration a fallback and prevent the object graph from becoming cyclic or ambiguous.

So long story short, in case you wish to prevent building object graphs based on runtime conditions, you should either add the selection logic to the decorator or create a separate selector ‘decorator’. If you no matter what, which to apply the decorator during object graph construction, you can use the runtime decorator examples of the CodeSamples project.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I think the first solution is the one that will work for me. The decorators can be chained together so using a selector seems like it would get over complicated or not suitable. In the case where I use a run-time context object, would I need to create a new Simple Injector container to represent each unit of work I am passed. At run-time I receive a list of config objects to process in parallel. It seems like the SI container should be scoped to each of these requests?

Comment: @user1574775: When doing parallel processing, you should typically give each operation/thread its own scope and resolve services inside that scope. This ensures that each operation runs in isolation.

Comment: That makes sense. What would the registration of the IRuntimeConfigProvider look like inside the scope? Should I access the container and register a manually created instance of IRuntimeConfigProvider? Such as:                 container.Register<IRuntimeConfigProvider>(() => new RuntimeConfigProvider { Configuration = runtimeConfig }, Lifestyle.Scoped);

Comment: No, that would still cause object graph composition to depend on runtime data. That runtimeConfig should be set _after_ you resolved an object graph. Perhaps construction can even be concealed within the provider itself, but that depends on where that runtime data is actually coming from.

Comment: I can edit the original question and provide more information and context. I'm not sure if that would be frowned upon? I can create a new question if that's more appropriate. Please let me know what you prefer.

Comment: Well, I don't have any problems with that, and I will try to answer any updste you make.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I've edited my original question with what I hope is enough context.